# 'Project cannot open the file' when trying to open MSProject mpp file by using pywin32

Tags: python, vba, pywin32, ms-project

I am using pywin32 to extract data from an MSProject (.mpp) file.
Everything had gone well until I installed the Japanese version of MSProject on my PC.

The error message shown as below comes out every time when I tried to open a mpp file by pywin32. Is there any piece of suggestions? Thanks!

I have tried:

- restarting my PC
- repairing MS Office in Apps & Features settings

```py
import win32com
try:
  mppFileName="Project.mpp"
  mpp=win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('MSProject.Application')
  mpp.FileOpen(mppFileName)
except Exception as e:
  print(str(e))
```

(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (1004, '', 'Project cannot open the file.', 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\VBAPJ.CHM\x00', 131072, 0), None)

Answer (score 2):

After changing the file address into the Absolute Address, the problem has gone.
That is,

```py
import win32com
try:
  mppFileName="C:/Project.mpp"
  ...
```

Reference: [[python-win32] Error when trying to open a Microsoft Project file](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2007-May/005949.html)